# Python Code not clear (arrays)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have the following lines:

```
Xtest = numpy.arange(-15,15,0.1)
Xtest = numpy.array([Xtest,Xtest*0+1]).T
```

Why does the second line look like this in the sense of **"Xtest*0+1"** ? I've tried

```
Xtest = numpy.array([Xtest,1]).T
```

I get the same output except that at the end of the array I have "dtype=object". Why is that?
Also, not clear what happens when I try

```
Xtest = numpy.array([Xtest,Xtest*0]).T
```

The output is unclear to me. Thought that I would have *Xtest* column with the column of 0's...
Finally,

```
Xtest =numpy.array([Xtest,0]).T
```

Why am I getting the second column with ones instead of zeros?

Comment: What is the output you are trying to get?

Comment: http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I just want to understand why the code does what it does.

Comment: FYI: After `Xtest = numpy.arange(-15,15,0.1)`, you could replace `Xtest*0+1` with `np.ones_like(Xtest)`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser The output is different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Xtest` is an array, it has more than one entry.  When you multiply it by zero, you have that many zeroes.  Then you add one to make it into an array full of one's.  In contrast, when you directly put in `1`, you end up with a single `1`, which is different.

Comment: Well, putting a single 1 does not return an error. The output still looks the same. Except for the "dtype=object".